# Counting subnets

Tags: subnet

I'm reading about subnetting but have problems with these topologies. The book says that network1 has 4 subnets and network2 has 12 subnets. But I count only 11 subnets in netork2 ? If there is a switch between 2 routers, you have to count it only once i thought?

Thanks in advance for helping me

Network 1: http://i50.tinypic.com/2urp7di.jpg Network 2: http://i50.tinypic.com/2rwus10.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are 12 subnets total.  Perhaps you just mis-counted?

You are correct, the switch is (presumably) a L2 device, and doesn't do routing.  It's all one subnet.